# AJAX function( ) part alone not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

After `function()` it is not working, i don't know why. If I put an alert before that statement it's working but after that statement it isn't working.

```
<script>
function new_order() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    alert("asdasd");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("order_id").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "item_sort.php?sort=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `onreadystatechange` callback is not executed or what? Please describe the problem better.

Comment: its works well and good for me.Show me where you are putting the alert..And one more thing ...check for any console errors which may be blocking the alert to fire

Comment: Why don't you check ajax errors? It would be the first thing to do before calling for help, IMHO.

Comment: str ? please check and you code working well. onreadystatechange  function will be call on callback try to paste full url instead of item_sort.php

Comment: iJay : I had used the alert inside the function() and outside the function().. But it worked outside the function() only...

Comment: As an aside, what's the point of `if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {...` when you don't allow an `else` case and the rest of your code assumes the if test will be successful?

Comment: everything is working except tis part...


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("order_id").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

Comment: And the readyState is always 0

Comment: @Venktesh : Check for errors in your browser console..

Comment: *"And the readyState is always 0"* So the callback **is** executed, but the `if` condition is not fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

3 things you can check

- If an element corresponding to id `order_id` exists on the page
- if the `str` is not null or not defined
- If you are using older IE versions IE5 or 6 you need to add the
  following in your code.

  ```
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  ```

Also you need to use the following way if you want to do POST ajax call.

```
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "item_sort.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send("sort=" + str);
```